# Can i have ubuntu in the same bootable usb stick for windows and mac?

Tags: windows, usb, macosx

I would like to have in the same usb 2 partitions one for mac and the other for run ubuntu over windows.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The USB boot is based upon what version of ubuntu you want to install, not what other OS was or will be on the machine.

So yes, one stick to rule them all.